# Does Pandas DataFrame bracket accessor [ ] prefer columns or rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm intrigued/confused by this example from [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

> Selecting a single column, which yields a Series, equivalent to df.A

```
In [23]: df['A']  
Out[23]:   
2013-01-01    0.469112  
2013-01-02    1.212112
```

and

> Selecting via [], which slices the rows.

```
In [24]: df[0:3]  
Out[24]:   
                   A         B         C         D  
2013-01-01  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632  
2013-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236  
2013-01-03 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
```

It's not clear to me how the first accessor "knows" to pick columns and the second knows to pick rows. It's a little annoying to me since I want to access columns by index too.

Answer (score 3):

The primary usage for `[]` is accessing columns. However, when you pass a slice, it [slices the rows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#slicing-ranges):

> With DataFrame, slicing inside of [] slices the rows. This is provided
>   largely as a convenience since it is such a common operation.

In order to access columns by integer index, you need to use `.iloc`. For example to access columns at positions 2 and 3 you would use `df.iloc[:, 2:4]`. Note that this is based on the position of the columns. You may have columns named 2 and 3 but if they are not at those positions, it will not select them. If you want to select by labels, you would use `.loc`. For example if you want to get columns B through D: `df.loc[:, "B":"D"]`. This, unlike the integer slicing, will give you column D, too. For details: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select column by number, you can't use single brackets:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,5], 'b':[3,4,6]})

In [260]: df[:,1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-260-ff65926f441e> in <module>()
----> 1 df[:,1]
```

You need to use `iloc` for selecting columns by number:

```
In [262]: df.iloc[:,1]
Out[262]:
0    3
1    4
2    6
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

For both lines slicing and columns selection by number use `iloc`:

```
In [263]: df.iloc[0:2,1]
Out[263]:
0    3
1    4
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

For both lines slicing and selecting columns by names, use `loc`:

```
In [267]: df.loc[0:2,'a']
Out[267]:
0    1
1    2
2    5
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Hope this helps for slicing/selecting with the different conventions.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `df[1:3]` syntax you are accessing the rows. When you use the `df['col_name']` syntax you're accessing the columns.

If you want to show only rows that match a given value use:

```
new_df1 = df[ df['col_name'] == 5 ]

new_df2 = df[ df['col_name'] >= 7 ]

new_df3 = df[ df['col_name'].isin(list_of_values) ]
```

Hope this saves you a few hours of looking at documentation.